# How to disable click event in cell table html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have table in html, I want to disable click event in any cell of table (`th, td, tr`) using jQuery or JavaScript. How can I do it?

```html
<table id="table1" border="1px">
<tr>
  <th>Title1</th>
  <td>Orange</td>
  <th>Title2</th>
  <td>Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Title3</th>
  <td>Food</td>
  <th>Title4</th>
  <td>Fish</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: CSS maybe? `pointer-events: none` Although it would help to know how and when you're attaching the event handlers you want to avoid

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your hint works but what if the column contains a button, input or another field that need to be clicked ? So the goal became: prevent the click event on the column but allow it on the child objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#table1").click(function(e){
          if (e.target !== this)
            return;
            alert('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table1" border="1px">
    <tr>
      <th>Title1</th>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <th>Title2</th>
      <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Title3</th>
      <td>Food</td>
      <th>Title4</th>
      <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If by disabling click event you mean disabling the event listeners, then the try the `off` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#disable-button').on('click',function(){
    $('#table1').off('click');
  });
  
  $('#table1').on('click',function(){
      alert('click event happened');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1px">
<tr>
  <th>Title1</th>
  <td>Orange</td>
  <th>Title2</th>
  <td>Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Title3</th>
  <td>Food</td>
  <th>Title4</th>
  <td>Fish</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button id="disable-button">Disable listener</button>
```

Otherwise, a very simple way to do would be using pure CSS:

```
pointer-events:none
```

But since you want to do it in jquery instead:

If you're using jQuery versions 1.4.3+:

```
$('selector').click(false);
```

If not:

```
$('selector').click(function(){ return false; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, afaik, you haven't registered any click events in the code, so its considered as if you don't have them.
Also, what @RoryMcCrossan said also for the mouse to show no events. or   `cursor:default` for normal cursor icon (arrow)